# grep a line with single number

Tags: unix, grep

I have a file with a few lines like this:

```
1 ab
11 ad
41 ac
1 af
1 ag
```

and I want the lines where the number is `1`:

```
1 ab
1 af
1 ag
```

How can I achieve this?

If I write this:

```
grep "1" file.txt
```

then I get all the lines that contain `1`, even if that's not the entire number:

```
1 ab
11 ad
41 ac
1 af
1 ag
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-w` option tells `grep` to search for a pattern as a single word:

```
grep -w 1 file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write:

```
grep '^1 ' file.txt
```

to get all lines that start with a `1` followed by a space. (The `^` means "start-of-line".)

Answer (score 0):

```
grep -w ^1 file.txt
```

To get lines starting with a one.

This is probably very useful for [regex with grep](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/grep-regular-expressions/).

Answer (score 0):

```
grep "^1[ \t]" file.txt
```

`^` -> beginning of line

`[ \t]` -> whitespace after "1"